# How to create test cases result or any new item in Rally app

Tags: testing, rally

I have a custom app report that shows test cases not run for test set. I need to have a button/link upon clicking of which I can enter a test case result. So far the code that I have is opening up the correct test case result window but upon clicking Save it hangs. When I checked the console output for this hanging window it showed that session was unknown. So the question is can this be achieved with custom generated link and pass the session somehow or the approach should be entirely different. Currently I am using 2.0.p5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an app that uses `Rally.nav.Manager.create` to instantiate a TestCaseResult editor in response to a button click from a grid cell, in turn based on this answer: [How to add a custom button on grid and pass row values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240507/how-to-add-a-custom-button-on-grid-and-pass-row-values)

https://github.com/markwilliams970/TestCaseGrid-AddResults